# How to add parameters for multiple agents to exclude from the SSRS Stats Report

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2014, ssrs-2012, optional-parameters

**Scenario:**
I have a report that pulls up stats for agents for a certain date range (usually the same day, yesterday) which I've set as parameters. I've built the report in Visual Studio Report builder and the report works great.

**Challenge:**
Some agents are taken off calls and work on emails instead that day. So, though they are logged in, they can't be added to the call queue stats.

**Need:**
I need to add parameters which can select agents from the drop down (Ctrl+select) and have the report run where employeeID NOT IN the ones that were selected. Then I need to add those parameters in the report builder to show as a drop-down so the user can ctrl+select the agents to exclude.

**Question:**
I know how to create 1 parameter to exclude 1 agent. How do I create parameter(s) to exclude more than 1 agent? Sometimes, it can be 0 agents, sometimes they are 10.

I'm using MS SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a parameter to your dataset query e.g.
Assuming some very simple tables for illustration with AgentID being a unique key of Agents.

```
SELECT {your list of columns} FROM AgentCalls 
WHERE 
(AgentID NOT IN (@myParamName) OR ISNULL(AgentID,'')='')
```

This will show all Agents if nothing is selected or it will exclude agents if any are selected.

You then need to populate the list of available items for your parameter, in this case it will be a list of Agents.
So create another dataset called, say dsAgents
With a query something like

```
SELECT AgentID, AgentName FROM Agents ORDER BY AgentName
```

In the parameter settings, make the parameter multi-value and also allow blank & null, in available values, choose dsAgents as the query,  use the AgentID field as the Value and the AgentName field as the Label.

SSRS will automatically convert the list of selected parameter values into a comma separated list and use in the IN clause, there is nothing more you need to do.

**P.S. this is from memory at 1am so it might not be spot on but it should be good enough to follow.**

**Note:** there is no need to hold control the parameter list will show checkboxes.

Comment: Thank you @Alan-Schofield. That worked. However, It works only when I select the NOT IN part. For some reason, it doesn't like the OR ISNULL part. If I comment out the OR ISNULL part, it works.    

So my code looks like this:   AND AgentReporting NOT IN (@AgentName)  --This works    BUT....

AND (AgentReporting NOT IN (@AgentName) OR ISNULL(AgentReporting,''))   --This doesn't work.

Comment: ISNULL does not return a boolean value.  In the code provided, the ISNULL function will return an empty string when AgentReporting is null since that is specified as the second parameter.  Instead, try ...OR AgentReporting IS NULL.

Comment: Sorry, it was 1 in the morning! It should have read ... OR ISNULL(AgentID,'') = '')  I did it this way so both blank or null values from the parameter are treated the same way.

Comment: I tried  ...OR ISNULL(AgentID,'') = '')    >>  Still didn't let me bypass selecting an agent from the drop down. It asked me to select an agent to proceed.

Comment: Can you post the parameter setup from the rdl and a screenshot of the report when you run it. Allowing null values should let you select the NULL checkbox next to the parameter and allowing blanks should let you leave it empty. I've never come across an issue with this.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
SELECT {your list of columns} FROM AgentCalls 
WHERE 
(AgentID NOT IN (@myParamName) OR @myParamName is ISNULL)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).