# Report Builder - How to allow Multiple Selection allowed parameter drop-down to accept Null

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, reportbuilder

I created a report on VS Report Builder from a query I wrote on SQL Server 2014.

The Report has two parameters:

1. The date the report should run for.
2. The agent to exclude from the report.

The query has conditions for the date and where agent NOT IN (agents selected from the drop-down)

Sometimes, there are no agents to exclude. Hence, the report should run even when there are no agents selected.

The report runs fine when there is at least 1 agent selected. But doesn't run at all when no agents are selected. Gives me an error message, "Please select value for the parameter 'Select Agent' ".

In Parameter properties, I have selected 'Text' as Data type. I have also checked 'Allow blank value("")' and 'Allow Multiple values'.

In the Available Values tab, I have selected 'Get values from a query' because I have a separate dataset that pulls records of the agent names from a separate table.

In Default Values tab, I have selected No Default Value. Maybe, I should select 'Specify Values' instead. But what should I specify the value as? Because, when I selected 'Specify values' and added a (Null) value, I got an error message that says 'A null default value was specified for the parameter but the parameter does not allow null values.'  I even tried specifying an obscure '1111111' as the default value. Still got the error message to select an agent.

Comment: This is a continuation of your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42797825/how-to-add-parameters-for-multiple-agents-to-exclude-from-the-ssrs-stats-report . If you allow nulls on the parameter and use the modified code in my final comment there it should work.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to handle this is to add an option to your Available Values that can be used to skip that parameter. You would add it by using a `Union All` in the query that the parameter is being populated from. For the label you could use something like "N/A" and the value can be NULL. This way, you will be able to specify it as a Default Value and users will be able to select it when there are no appropriate real values. Finally, it sounds like you may have already done this, but make sure your query will handle the parameter being NULL and still give you the correct results.

EDIT:

```
SELECT AgentID, AgentName
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT AgentID, AgentFirstName + ' ' + AgentLastName [AgentName] 
    FROM AgentStats 
    WHERE MidnightStartDate >= dateadd(day, -60, getdate()) AND MidnightStartDate < getdate()
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'N/A', NULL 
) A
ORDER BY AgentName
```

The union adds the `NULL` value to the results. This is all wrapped in a subquery so that you can still use the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: Thank you. I was contemplating that but hadn't done it yet because I thought there might've been an easier way to do it just within the report builder itself.   >>>  I did add an option in the query that allowed an IS NULL. But the drop-down didn't allow it to get to that point. >>> I will try adding a Null Value in the dataset for the list of agents.

Comment: I tried inserting values into the temp table but I got an error that that temp table already exists in the database.  >>>>  Please can you show me how to use a Union All to add that extra value?

Comment: If you post the existing query I can show you how to union the NULL value to it.

Comment: Thank you @StevenWhite >>>>   SELECT DISTINCT AgentID, AgentFirstName + ' ' + AgentLastName [AgentName]

FROM AgentStats

WHERE MidnightStartDate >= dateadd(day, -60, getdate())
     AND MidnightStartDate <  getdate() 

ORDER BY AgentName